# Safari: After 6 concurrent XMLHttpRequest requests, progress block won't get called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari, xmlhttprequest

I am building a multiple file upload `jQuery` script, and am using `XMLHttpRequest` and `FormData` to upload files. Works great.

But, from testing and what I have read, you can only have 6 concurrent `XMLHttpRequest` requests at the same time. From my testing this is correct, but after any of those 6 complete, the next ones in the queue will upload, which is what one would expect.

The issue arises with the progress function. This function is only getting called for the first 6 files when using **Safari**, but the next files that get queued do NOT call the progress method. Firefox and Chrome perform correctly and show progress for all files. Here is what I am using:

```
_makeRequest: function(asset) {
    var _this = this;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    (function(progress) { 
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                _this._progress(asset, e);
            } else {
                _this._log('Error: 'asset.file.name+' not computable');
            }
        };
    }(asset.progress));
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        _this._complete(e, _this);
    });
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        _this._failed(e, _this);
    });
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("abort", function(e) {
        _this._canceled(e, _this);
    });
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("loadstart", function(e) {
        _this._start(e, _this);
    });
    xhr.open("POST", this.assetBuilder.url);
    xhr.send(this._formData(asset));
}
```

**Is there a way to get the queued files to also call the progress function in Safari so that I can update my UI progress bar?**

Comment: What browser does this happen in? What do you mean by "queued"? Are you manually queuing files to upload, or do you expect the browser to queue connections?

Comment: @Bergi - This seems to be only happening in Safari.

Comment: In that case, I'd call it a browser bug :-)